# With symbolic links, why are the results from "ls .." and "cd .. " different?

Tags: shell, symlink

Suppose I execute the following commands:

```
$ mkdir -p a/b
$ ln -s a/b c
$ cd c
```

Then, in directory **c**, why does `ls ..` display the contents of directory **a**, but `cd ..` returns to the original directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell distinguishes between two types of paths: physical paths, which reflect the actual layout of folders on disk, and logical paths, which take into account symbolic links. When you changed your working directory to `c` (instead of `a/b`), the shell knows that the logical path to the current directory is `~/c` (assuming `a` is in your home directory), and that the physical path is `~/a/b`.

In your example, `ls` shows the contents of `a` because `..` is an actual file system entry for the physical parent directory of `c`. The working directory, on the other hand, is a shell concept, and `cd` is a shell built-in command. The shell knows that although `c` is just another name for `a/b`, the working directory is specifically `c`, not `a/b`. Therefore, it parses `..` logically instead of physically.

The POSIX standard specifies `-L` and `-P` options to the `cd` command to let you explicit say which path to follow. In your example, `cd c; cd -P ..` should put you in `~/b` instead of `~`.

Comment: I believe your last line example meant to read `cd c; cd -P ..`